# Reshape pandas dataframe rows

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataset in a excel from pandas like this :
row :  123567,  column  ABCDEF

```
      A B C D E  F
1   0  5  7 1  8 6
2   2  3  2 4  1 5
3   3  1  1  2 3 4
5   3 5  5  7 9  4
6  4  5  4  6  7 7
7  6  8  3  3  1 2
```

but i want make a data following this :
3 row be a one row

```
1   0 5 7 1 8 6  2 3 2 4 1 5 3 1 1 2 3 4
2   3 5 5 7 9 4 4 5 4 6 7 7 6 8 3 3 1 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest, and probably most simple method would be to just call `reshape` on the values:

```
df.values.reshape(-1, df.shape[1] * 3)

array([[0, 5, 7, 1, 8, 6, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [3, 5, 5, 7, 9, 4, 4, 5, 4, 6, 7, 7, 6, 8, 3, 3, 1, 2]])
```

This, however, will error out if your data does not have the exact number of rows to perform a reshape.

---

You can also use `groupby` + `apply`:

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3 * 3).apply(lambda x: x.values.ravel())
```

This should work even if the first option does not.

Comment: thankyou for your help. i have one question again. can you help me how to use data like before, but the result is stored in excel by using loop in excel writer?